# Is Android Studio Emulator supposed to be very buggy and glitchy?

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator

I am currently developing an Android app without an Android device. 
Therefore, unwillingly, I am using Android Studio's emulator as my only source of testing.

However, half the time I use the emulator, the program glitches and the app either stops or does not trigger the functionalities that I put in.
However, the other half of the time (I did not change any line of code when doing this), I'll simply run the emulator again and the app will function normally.

But now I am concerned about this because I am not certain if this is only a bug in the emulator or if the same thing will happen in a real device. Since I do not have an android device, there's no way for me to text this in a real setting.

Can I just ignore this glitch? or is this actually an issue?

Comment: post the error message. You should post your Android Emulator configuration.Also you should post the computers configuration here

Comment: I get . Emulator: 2018-11-07 10:50:29.630 qemu-system-x86_64[18790:941516] IMKInputSession [0x7fbee22a5c00 presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler:] : [self textInputContext]=0x7fbee2188520 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.},

Comment: Android emulator works quite good for me. I think, there is some configuration issue on your machine.

Comment: I tried different machines and they all act the same..

Comment: I'm having tons of issues with network related glitches. Latest Android Studio, brand new emulator, and I keep randomly getting network issues. It seems to send out a request, I can confirm that the server gets the request and responds, but somehow the response never makes it back properly. Doing the same things on a real Android device never have these issues.

Comment: After 4 years it is still very broken